# Issue of CCM with Different version of Cassandra

Tags: python, python-2.7, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, ccm

Cassandra clustrer 2.2.9 is working fine with CCM but when I created a cluster with 3.7 its throwing following error:

```
C:\Users\Admin>ccm start
Started: node1 with pid: 4844
Started: node3 with pid: 4060
Started: node2 with pid: 2172
Started: node4 with pid: 5816

C:\Users\Admin>ccm stop
SUCCESS: The process with PID 4844 has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 4060 has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 2172 has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 5816 has been terminated.

C:\Users\Admin>ccm node1 versionfrombuild
2.2.9

C:\Users\Admin>ccm switch Tombstone_exp

C:\Users\Admin>ccm start
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\ccm.py", line 4, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').run_script('ccm==3.1.5', 'ccm.py')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 658, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1445, in run_script
    exec(script_code, namespace, namespace)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\ccm-3.1.5-py2.7.egg\EGG-INFO\scripts\ccm.py", line 105, in <module>

  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\ccmlib\cmds\cluster_cmds.py", line 491, in run
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\ccmlib\cluster.py", line 398, in start
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\ccmlib\node.py", line 696, in start
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\ccmlib\node.py", line 1784, in __clean_win_pid
Exception: Timed out waiting for pid file.

C:\Users\Admin>ccm node1 versionfrombuild
3.7

C:\Users\Admin>pip freeze
ccm==3.1.4
psutil==2.2.1
PyYAML==3.12
six==1.11.0
```

Operating system: Windows 7
Powersell execution policy in unrestricted. 
I checked CCM github available release version is 3.1.4

Comment: is anything in the `system.log` files?

Comment: What does `ccm node1 showlog` say?

Comment: logs (C:\Users\Admin\.ccm\Tombstone_exp\node1\logs) directory is empty. 

    C:\Users\Admin>ccm node1 showlog 
    C:\Users\Admin>Cannot access file C:\Users\Admin\.ccm\Tombstone_exp\node1\logs\system.log

Comment: Try killing all cassandra related processes. Also, might be easier if you do a restart of computer. I think that the previous running cassandra has not been stopped completely/correctly. Let me know if that helped.